# Storing a sparse matrix in blocks in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have to perform this operation:

```
N = A'*P*A
```

The structure of the P matrix is block diagonal while the A matrix is largely sparse (also in a banded structure). The multiplication is performed in blocks. But the problem is storage.

The N matrix is too huge to store in full (out of memory when trying to allocate). So, I want to store in a sparse fashion. While the sparse command generates only the  values in row,column format, can it be applied to store banded matrices with the row column as the index of the block?

I have tried [spalloc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spalloc.html) given in the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655341/matlab-extract-block-diagonals-of-large-sparse-matrix) question but it hasnt helped storing the row and index of the block. 
Thank you.

[image]
Image for A P A' formation

The problem lies in the blocks. The blocks are themselves sparse. So is it possible to make blocks as sparse matrices themselves while saving. 
So, if a block has a row = 1 and col = 1, then can this be done?

```
N(row,col) = sparse(A'*P*A)
```

Comment: Could you provide some example code that creates a similar A and P of interest?

Comment: @Steve I have shared an image for the A and P to show the structure.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? If you know the coordinates inside the block, the size of all blocks, and which block it is; then you know everything already.

Comment: I want to achieve two levels of sparseness, storing the individual blocks as sparse matrices. Is it possible to do?

Comment: @shunyo define all your blocks as sparse and then perform the multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some additional tricks to play but the first thing to try is to make sure the full matrix `N` is never created in memory. The immediate problem is that if you call `sparse(A'*P*A)` then you multiple `A'*P` then `(A'*P)`*A and only then do you make it sparse and take out the zeros. Right before making it sparse, the entire non-sparse matrix representation of `N` is in memory. To force MATLAB to be smarter do the following:

```
SA = sparse(A);
N =  SA'*sparse(P)*SA;
whos N
```

You should see that N is sparse but, more importantly, each multiplication result is sparse as well because you are multiplying a sparse matrix times a sparse matrix.